# Get the correct remoteAddress through a proxied apache request

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I have this configuration in my Apache virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin contact@black-frames.net
        ServerName black-frames.net

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9150/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9150/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/blackframes_error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/blackframes_access.log combined

        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

But on Play Framework, asking for the client IP (request.remoteAddress) results in a `127.0.0.1`.

I'm sure it's because of the proxy, but I don't know which parameter to set to make this works.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a proxy server, you need to look at the [X-Forwarded-For header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead of the remote address (source IP).

Comment: Exactly! That was the way to look. But I had to add `XForwardedSupport=127.0.0.1` in the application.conf file to make this works. You set me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear that from you!